# Laravel - Trying to update data in controller data in view with button click

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I normally use Laravel for pure API backend calls only, however, recently I require the need to build some simple front end views for my app.

Normally working with AngularJS for anything front end, I thought Laravel and blade would be similar, but I seem to be struggling with (what I thought) was basic functionality.

My use case is this:
I have some tabled data displayed on a view `($data)`.  Also on my view I have a start date `($startDate)` and an end date `($endDate)`, all of which I pass in from the controller using the `->with()` statement.  I am assuming this is the best way?

```
return View::make( 'reports' )->with( ['data' =>$data, 'startDate' => $startDate, 'endDate' => $endDate] );
```

I am trying to achieve the functionality of clicking on a back button or a forward button and having both the `$startDate` and `$endDate` shift forward or back a week and returning a new set of `$data`.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: Blade is a templating language. It is nothing like angular. The closest thing to angular you'd find in Laravel would be [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/)

Comment: @apokryfos Yes I understand, but I was more asking how it is achieved in Laravel, not so much trying to compare against Angular.

Comment: Usually you'd craft links with the appropriate parameters in the page and then clicking on the link will load the same view but with different values for the variables e.g. your button could link to `reports?startDate=2020-11-23&endDate=2020-11-30` for last week and you'd resolve the query string to variables to pass to the view

Comment: So how would I go about modifying date ranges within the view to build new links each time?

Comment: That depends. How are you currently building your links and what do you currently do in your controller?

Comment: My view is accessed by a single `Route::get()` and my controller simply runs an SQL query and returns the data into `$data`.

Comment: You should modify it to accept input parameters and use them to filter the relevant data. You haven't shared much detail so I don't really know what the way to go is here